# How to include a child object's child object in Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-4.1

I am using `Entity Framework 5 code first` and `ASP.NET MVC 3`.

I am struggling to get a child object's child object to populate.  Below are my classes..

Application class;

```
public class Application
{
     // Partial list of properties

     public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Child class:

```
public class Child
{
     // Partial list of properties

     public int ChildRelationshipTypeId { get; set; }

     public virtual ChildRelationshipType ChildRelationshipType { get; set; }
}
```

ChildRelationshipType class:

```
public class ChildRelationshipType
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Part of GetAll method in the repository to return all the applications:

```
return DatabaseContext.Applications
     .Include("Children");
```

The Child class contains a reference to the ChildRelationshipType class.  To work with an application's children I would have something like this:

```
foreach (Child child in application.Children)
{
     string childName = child.ChildRelationshipType.Name;
}
```

I get an error here that the object context is already closed.

How do I specify that each child object must include the `ChildRelationshipType` object like what I did above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Include Multiple Levels of Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties)

Answer (score 292, accepted):

If you include the library `System.Data.Entity` you can use an overload of the `Include()` method which takes a lambda expression instead of a string. You can then `Select()` over children with Linq expressions rather than `string` paths.

```
return DatabaseContext.Applications
     .Include(a => a.Children.Select(c => c.ChildRelationshipType));
```

Comment: As GraemeMiller said, strongly typed classes are better for maintainability than using strings

Comment: Which version did the lamba method come available? I'm stuck on a EF 4.0 Codebase..and cant' get the lamdas to work.  Thanks for any input.

Comment: It will work in EF 4, just make sure to add a reference to `System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: FYI - In EF 6 the namespace is `Microsoft.Data.Entity`

Comment: Using EF 5, I could not get .Select(x => x.Child) but this worked -            Entities.UserProfile storedProfile = db.UserProfiles
                                                    .Include(s => s.ShippingAddress)
                                                    .Include(st => st.ShippingAddress.StateProvince)
                                                    .Include(b => b.BillingAddress)
                                                    .Include(bs => bs.BillingAddress.StateProvince)
                                                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == userId);

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the correct library to use, all too often people omit this important nugget of information.

Answer (score 170):

With EF Core in .NET Core you can use the keyword `ThenInclude` :

```
return DatabaseContext.Applications
 .Include(a => a.Children).ThenInclude(c => c.ChildRelationshipType);
```

Include childs from childrens collection :

```
return DatabaseContext.Applications
 .Include(a => a.Childrens).ThenInclude(cs => cs.ChildRelationshipType1)
 .Include(a => a.Childrens).ThenInclude(cs => cs.ChildRelationshipType2);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Really helpful! Sometimes you might get wrong intellisense, just ignore that and build! :)

Comment: Nice one, I was looking for .net core :)

Comment: And what if Children is a collection and I need to include properties under it?

Comment: Found an overload for that. Was not obvious at first.

Comment: Think you've got an extra parenthesis at the end there ;)

Comment: @dodbrian What was the overload?  I'm trying to nest .ThenInclude, where the child is a collection.

Comment: Glad I didn't stop at the first "answer" :)

Answer (score 26):

I ended up doing the following and it works:

```
return DatabaseContext.Applications
     .Include("Children.ChildRelationshipType");
```

Comment: The strongly typed way is better.  Magic strings aren't good for refactoring

Comment: @GraemeMiller , you re right, it is a lot better when debugging, refactoring or changing the code in any way, but (sadly) "strongly typed" just does not work - for me. So I'm stuck with magic stings.

Comment: I will go with a solution using `nameof` expressions: `string.join('.', nameof(Children), nameof(Children.ChildRelationshipType))` - at least I will be able to "FindAllReferences"

Answer (score 3):

A good example of using the Generic Repository pattern and implementing a generic solution for this might look something like this.

```
public IList<TEntity> Get<TParamater>(IList<Expression<Func<TEntity, TParamater>>> includeProperties)

{

    foreach (var include in includeProperties)
     {

        query = query.Include(include);
     }

        return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: How would I call the above method? could you provide an example

Comment: @Jamee -List<Expression<Func<PersonObject, object>>> includers = new List<Expression<Func<PersonObject, object>>>();
            includers.Add(x => x.FirstName); Get<PersonObject>(includers);

Comment: And query comes from...?

Comment: Sorry @DougBeard, not following your question.

Comment: @gcoleman0828  The query variable in your code snippet above.  Is it magically instantiated?  Where does it come from?

Comment: @DougBeard: the query can be extracted via dbContext.Person.Where clause, a query builder, or from an IEnumerable in which you apply AsQueryable()