# Stop entity framework loading, when setting property as virtual

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In entity framework, i know that you can set a property as virtual to get it too lazy load, which is great.  But in my service code i would like to load a list of children, and also a list in each of those children.

Instead of getting entity framework to load this data, i can load the data in 2 hits.

Here is an example, of my classes

```
public class Parent
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long ParentId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<GrandChild> { get; set; }
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long ChildId { get; set; }

    public virtual AnotherClass AnotherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In my service code i am loading the data like this, as i cant see to be able to load all of them at once (maybe i just dont know the correct query syntax)

```
var parent = await _context.Parents
    .Where(e => e.Id == 9)
    .Include(e => e.Children)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var grandchildren = await _context.GrandChildrens
    .Where(e => e.Child.ParentId == 9)
    .ToListAsync();

// this is load again?
foreach (var child in parent.Children)
    child.GrandChildren = (from a in grandChildren where a.ChildId == child.Id).ToList();
```

Now everytime i am trying to set `child.GrandChildren`, entity framework is trying to load the data.  How can i stop it loading the data, but without removing the `virtual` keyword, as in other instances, i would like entity framework to lazy load.

Also, if anyone knows how to load parent, child, grandchildren in 1 query, please let me know too

Comment: If you want all entities to be loaded at once, you should load them eagerly then.

Comment: In this case, that is what i am trying to do, but entity framework is trying to load them, when i am setting the property.  If i let Entity Framework load the lists, it would cause 3 connections, where as if i do it, i can do it in 2.  This is a sample, on larger objects i can load the data in far less connections then entity framework

Comment: have you read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047845/how-to-include-a-child-objects-child-object-in-entity-framework-5

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned about connections since ADO uses connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load related entities eagerly like following:

```
var parent = await _context.Parents
    .Where(e => e.Id == 9)
    .Include(e => e.Children.GrandChildrens)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This should load parents, their children and their grand children.