Entity Framework Core : conditionally include children of already included property
I have a Song model which has a Song.SongArtistRelations field which is a list of SongArtistRelation objects. It represents a many-to-many relation.
I have implemented a search for songs. However, I want lazy-load, and load full data of artists only if needed in query.
I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.
Full code avaiable at: https://github.com/danisuba10/Musify-o/blob/main/Application/Songs/SearchSongs.cs
At the beginning I include SongArtistRelations:
var query = _context.Songs
                .Include(s => s.SongArtistRelations)
                .AsQueryable();

Then later on I check if I need to include artists or just their IDs are needed. A solution for this I found was this, but I get an error:
if (request.IncludeArtists)
{
    query = query.Include(s => s.SongArtistRelations.Select(ar => ar.Artist));
}

Error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 's.SongArtistRelations.AsQueryable().Select(ar => ar.Artist)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.g__ExtractIncludeFilter|36_0(Expression currentExpression, Expression includeExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude, Boolean setLoaded)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model,  Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_01.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func1 compiler)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.IncludableQueryable2.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable1.GetAsyncEnumerator()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Application.Songs.SearchSongs.Handler.Handle(Query request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Project Folder\CSHARP\Musify-o\Application\Songs\SearchSongs.cs:line 68

How can I later on conditionally include children, without doing an Include.ThenInclude as that way SongArtistRelations would be queried twice, causing performance issues.

The problem isn't the conditional operation, is query.Include(s => s.SongArtistRelations.Select(ar => ar.Artist)); itself. That's simply invalid. Use .ThenInclude if you want to load a nested object. Do that right after .Include(), not after adding other operators

The short answer - don't do that later on. Check the condition and include children in the correct place.

@PanagiotisKanavos
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Domain.Song>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Domain.Song, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Domain.SongArtistRelation>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Domain.Song, Domain.Album>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Domain.Song, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Domain.SongArtistRelation>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast

I can't guess what you wrote. Include.ThenInclude works.

Include.ThenInclude would surely work, but then we would need an if/else, so IDs are always included. I wanted it to do it like the way in the question, so if later on we have more things to search based on, we don't need an if/else for all of them.

So add that if/else. You can't add that after the entity information is lost. if later on we have more things to search based on rewrite the code so the query parameters are visible in the entire query creation process and apply the operators in the correct order. The LINQ operators already follow that pattern, with each one applied only to the correct variant of IQueryable<>, each producing a specific IQueryable<> variant.

Okay, thank you. I though that there is a way to do this to include children later on.
I saw an answers using the same thing with .Select at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13048469/12252530 however it does not seem to work.

It seems the problem is the way the rest of the code is written, not the conditional include. That doesn't change. If you want to conditionally add multiple operators, you can create a series of filters/methods that can be called in sequence, each applying a specific operator. BTW that's what LINQ does

EF 5 isn't EF Core 5. It's an ancient Entity Framework version released in 2012. Besides, the answer doesn't say what you assume. It doesn't say you can add Include later on, it shows what was used in 2012 when ThenInclude wasn't available

So the correct, industry standard way to implement this would be to create methods and move each part of the search to a specified method? And in the end, the way to do this is only possible with Include.ThenInclude? It would mean a lot to me if you could give a short example, or a source for that, so I can check.

What does your current code do and why do you assume it's more work than what you already do? var initialQuery= _context.Songs.Include(s => s.SongArtistRelations); if (request.IncludeArtists) initialQuery= initialQuery.ThenInclude(ar=>ar.Artist); This isn't about industry standards, it's about using a fluent API properly.

If it's "later on" then why use include over a separate query which might even be more efficient to begin with?

I believe you may have a bit of a misunderstanding of the Include/ThenInclude relationship.  The logic you seem to be looking for should be:
IQueryable<Song> query = _context.Songs
    .Include(s => s.SongArtistRelations);

// Could be other includes here, or Where conditions, etc.

if (request.IncludeArtists)
{
    query = query.Include(s => s.SongArtistRelations)
        .ThenInclude(ar => ar.Artist);
    // or just query = ((IIncludableQueryable<Song>) query).ThenInclude(ar => ar.Artist); if the check and execution occurs right after the SongArtistRelations inclusion.
}

Edit: If using the commented out version, ThenInclude() is only available on an IIncludableQueryable<TEntity> which is what Include() returns so it can be chained. Having the extra Include to chain in the ThenInclude() does not impact the generated SQL, but if you just want the ThenInclude() in the condition we need to cast it, and in that scenario NO other conditions like Where() etc. can occur between the Include() and the conditional ThenInclude() (The conditional ThenInclude() has to happen immediately after the Include().
When building a Linq query expression, EF is not generating SQL on the fly, so the above statement does not "query" or even join the SongArtistRelations more than once when including artists. It builds a query expression which EF will know when translating to SQL that you want the SongArtistRelations, then if including artists, also join in the Artist table. The SQL generation execution does not occur until you materialize the query with a ToList() / First() / Count() etc.

To have it neatly fit into Fluent API, you can do it as extension method, too: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D57QV8

That's a nifty implementation, I could see using something like that for IncludeIf() and WhereIf() instead of the if wrappers.

We actually have it as WhereIf but the implementations are similar.

@StevePy
`var query = _context.Songs.Include(s => s.SongArtistRelations).AsQueryable();
if (request.IncludeArtists)
{
query = query = query.ThenInclude(ar => ar.Artist);
}
`
Gives error, 'IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude' and no accessible extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
It seems like the way to do it is to just use Include.ThenInclude

Yeah, I was making an implementation of Fildor's IncludeIf/ThenIncludeIf etc. and you won't be able to use the commented out line as-written. ThenIncude can only be applied to an IIncludableQueryable<TEntity> not IQueryable<TEntity>. It is still do-able, but messier. I will update the answer.

Thank you for your update! I tried it out, but I get the error:
The type or namespace name 'IIncludableQueryable<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)CS0246
if (request.IncludeArtists) {     query = ((IIncludableQueryable<Song>)query).ThenInclude(ar => ar.Artist); }
Am I missing something?

Sorry, I'd written that from home and didn't have the implementation at hand. It is a weird one. ((Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.IIncludableQueryable<Song, SongArtistRelation>)query)...
