# Loading Related Entities in a Repository using EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my model, I have a `User` aggregate root, each of which has a collection of associated `Transactions`.  Each `Transaction` has a reverse navigation property `User`.

I need to get all of the `Transactions` at once, and this has resulted in the following query in my `UserRepository`

```
public ICollection<ITransaction> GetAllTransactions() {

    return (from u in Set.Include("Transactions") 
            from t in u.Transactions
            select t).ToList();       
}
```

`Set` is `IDbSet<User>` from the EF context.

The problem is that lazy-loading is not implemented (nor do I want to implement it) and the `Transaction.User` property after querying is `null`.   Everything is mapped through EF correctly.

What should the query be to retrieve all `Transactions` with a non-null `User`?

I am using EF6.

Comment: If you want the `User` property to be populated, then you need to `.Include("User")` on your transactions. Try `from t in u.Transactions.Include("User")` instead of `from t in u.Transactions`.

Comment: Can you not just do something like `select new t, t.User`

Comment: Apologies, `Set` is `IDbSet<User>` from the EF context

Comment: @mark no, you can't return an anonymous type from a non-dynamic method.

Comment: @Maarten I tried that but I got a compile/intellisense error that `Include` cannot be resolved. `User.Transactions` is an `ICollection<Transaction>`

Comment: @Graham if you can't find `.Include`, make sure you have `using System.Data.Entity;` at the top of the repository.cs file. It's an extension method, so you need the namespace to use it.

Comment: See [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties). It's either `Set.Include("Transactions").Include("Transactions.User")` or `Set.Include(s => s.Transactions).Include(s => s.Transactions.Select(t => t.User))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually `Include` the `Transaction.User`. It could be done after the final projection to `Transaction` like this

```
public ICollection<ITransaction> GetAllTransactions()
{    
    return Set.SelectMany(u => u.Transactions).Include(t => t.User).ToList();       
}
```