# Entity Framework - Include multiple level properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to get a table from database using entity framework.

The table has reference to other table which again has reference to other tables.
I know how to include other tables. And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties/10823103#10823103) answer and this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx#Anchor_1) including multiple levels are like this:

```
entity.TableLevel1.Include(tLvl1=>tLvl1.TableLevel2.Select(tLvl2=>tLvl2.TableLevel3));
```

But my question is, how to include another table at level 3 ?

This seems not to work:

```
entity.TableLevel1
          .Include(tLvl1=>tLvl1.TableLevel2
               .Select(tLvl2=>tLvl2.TableLevel3)
               .Select(tLvl2 => tLvl2.AnotherTableLevel3);
```

Comment: Please show us the table class code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add another `Include` call:

```
entity.TableLevel1.Include(tLvl1=>tLvl1.TableLevel2.Select(tLvl2=>tLvl2.TableLevel3))
                  .Include(tLvl1=>tLvl1.TableLevel2.Select(tLvl2=>tLvl2.AnotherTableLevel3));
```

If you want to load related entities that are at the same level you should call  `Include` extension method for each of them.

Answer (score 6):

You can make multiple `Include()` calls:

```
entity.TableLevel1.Include(t1 => t1.TableLevel2);
entity.TableLevel1.Include(t1 => t1.TableLevel2.Select(t2 => t2.TableLevel3));
entity.TableLevel1.Include(t1 => t1.TableLevel2.Select(t2 => t2.AnotherTableLevel3));
```

or

```
entity.TableLevel1.Include("TableLevel2");
entity.TableLevel1.Include("TableLevel2.TableLevel3");
entity.TableLevel1.Include("TableLevel2.AnotherTableLevel3");
```

But you can mark your navigation properties as `virtual` and will be lazy loading, so you dont need to make the `Include()` calls:

```
class TableLevel1
{
    public virtual TableLevel2 TableLevel2 { get; set; }
}

class TableLevel2
{
    public virtual TableLevel3 TableLevel3 { get; set; }

    public virtual TableLevel3 AnotherTableLevel3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Arturo, there are two things I want to warn you about your solutions. The first thing is your first `Include` call is unnecessary, that level is going to be loaded with  any of the other two `Include` calls. The second thing is if they want to use their entities in a place where its context was already disposed, lazy loading is not a option, an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Using EF 6.2 (not core) this gave me a headache for a few hours, only to find that the reason this wasn't working...

.Include("InspectionResultsByPerspective")
.Include("InspectionResultsByPerspective.InspectionResults")
.Include("InspectionResultsByPerspective.InspectionResults.PreparationTasksResults")

was because the type PreparationTasksResults had no default ctor!!! ahhh!

Give it a default ctor and you can include to your heart's content :) or so it seems for me

Comment: This must be for code first approach. Nobody cares about constructors if database first approach is used.