# include multiple objects inside an object [Entity framework]

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to retrieve both the list of ProjectCategories (subcategories) and the Categorie of a ProjectCategorie, the sub lists are retrieved. But I have no idea how to get the Categorie.

```
Project project = ctx.Projecten.Include(p => p.ProjectCategories.Select(s => s.Sub.Select(su => su.Sub))).ToList().Find(p => p.ProjectId == projectId);
```

These are the domain classes, as you can see I have a Categorie inside my ProjectCategorie:

```
public class ProjectCategorie
{
    public int ProjectCategorieId { get; set; }
    public double MinBedrag { get; set; }
    public double MaxBedrag { get; set; }
    public bool Aanpasbaar { get; set; }
    public bool AutoAanpasbaar { get; set; }

    public ProjectCategorie Super { get; set; }
    public List<ProjectCategorie> Sub { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Categorie Categorie { get; set; }
}

public class Categorie : BegrotingsPost
{

    public int CategorieId { get; set; }
    public string Beschrijving { get; set; }
    public double MinBedrag { get; set; }
    public double MaxBedrag { get; set; }

    public Begroting Begroting { get; set; }
    public BegrotingsPost Super { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How about using `Include(TEntity)` ?

Comment: could you explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Include Multiple Levels of Properties](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok update (mis read the question) ...

```
Project project = ctx.Projecten
   .Include(p => p.ProjectCategories.Select(s => s.Sub.Select(su => su.Sub)))
   .Include(p => p.ProjectCategories.Select(s => s.Categorie))
   .Find(p => p.ProjectId == projectId)
   .ToList();
```

I would probably do the find in the db too (might introduce a logic error else). 
Just moving the ToList() to the last line of the query will resolve that.

Comment: Like I said, the subs are retrieved, I need to be able to retrieve the Categorie for the ProjectCategorie too, but I don't know how

Comment: ah ok ... add another include ... hang tight i'll update my answer