# Entity Framework: InvalidOperationException when including mutiple levels of properties

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework core. I'm attempting to create a list of products and include associate reviews and review author data.

I have a 3 entities:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Review> Reviews {get; set;}
}

public class Review
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Product Product {get; set;}
        public Customer Author { get; set; }
}

public class Customer
{
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

When, refering to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10823103/1087131), I request a list of products with reviews and authors:

```
context.Products.Include(p=> p.Reviews.Select(r => r.Author)).ToList();
```

The following error is thrown:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   Message = The property expression 'p => {from Review r in [p].Reviews select [r].Author}' is not valid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you got any fluent mappings?

Comment: I have not fluent mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem to be something still not done or missing, but anyway you can do it like that:

```
context.Products.Include(p => p.Reviews).ThenInclude(x=>x.Author).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @Bassam :) However, in your example, the type of 'x' is ICollection<Review>, not Review. So I don't think this works.

Comment: @StevePaul this is exaclty like your query and it is working! just try it^^

Comment: My apoligies - you are right and I am wrong! For some reason, it was throwing compilation errors. I recompiled my model classes and the errors dissappeared! I'm very confused. But thank you for your time :)