# Query many to many relation with lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor, lambda

I'm using entity framework database first.

For one to many relation, in sql server, I use the following sql query(Status_ID is foreign key):

```
SELECT Products.*, Status.Title as Pstatus
FROM Products, Status 
WHERE Products.Status_ID = Status.ID
```

In MVC I use the following code to retrieve the same data as above sql query and pass the list to the View:

**Controller:**

```
var products = oDB.Products.Include(m => m.Status)
                       .ToList();
// string test = products[0].Status.Title;
return View(products);
```

In the view I can access the desired data by the following code:

**View:**

```
@model List<myDB.Product>
...
@item.Status.Title // This works well for each item in the list
```

---

For MANY TO MANY RELATIONS WITH JUNCTION TABLE, this is my .edmx:

[image]

Now How could I retrieve list of products including related categories?
I need the list of products and pas it to the view as a list, and access each product's categories in the view.

My Classes (These classes are generated automatically):

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Products_Categories> Products_Categories { get; set; }
}

public partial class Products_Categories
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Product_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Category_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}

public partial class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Products_Categories> Products_Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties and MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Can you show us the sets that are currently available in your oDB? As @PeterB pointed out, the key is to include the sets that you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var products = oDB.Products.Include(m => m.Product_Categories.Select(pc=>pc.Category))
                       .ToList();
// string test = products[0].Status.Title;
return View(products);
```

and in a view you could use it like this

```
@foreach(var item in model){ 
   <h3>string.join(", ", item.Product_Categories.Select(pc=>pc.Category.Title))</h3> 
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. But how could I access to Category.Title for example, in the view (Index.cshtml for instance)?

Comment: @foreach(var item in model){
<h3>string.join(", ", item.Product_Categories.Select(pc=>pc.Category.Title))</h3>
}

Comment: Unfortunately I get this string: System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[oDB.Products_Categories,System.String]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something like this:

```
var products = oDB.Products.Include("Status")
                   .ToList();
// string test = products[0].Status.Title;
return View(products);
```

Comment: This way is appropriate for one to many relationship in which Products table and Status table are connected to each other directly and without any junction table. Is it possible to include Categories table in a way like this?

Comment: Please post your classes.

Comment: I've edit my question and added classes definitions.

Comment: Please try this: `oDB.Products.Include("Products_Categories.Category").ToList();`

Comment: Thanks but then how could I access to Category.Title for example, in the view (Index.cshtml for instance)?

Comment: Try this: `@item.Products_Categories.Category.Title`

Comment: Unfortunately I get this exception: 'ICollection<Products_Categories>' does not contain a definition for 'Category' and no extension method 'Category' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<Products_Categories>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @item.Products_Categories.Single(a=>a.Product_ID==@item.ID).Category.Title