# Filtering include items in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, lambda, include

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties) and i've implemented in EntityFramework core a linq query.
Here is c# syntax:

```
    DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
    var actionMenuGroup = Context.ActionMenuGroups
                  .Include(am => am.ActionMenus)
                  .Where(am => am.ActionMenus.Any(amm => amm.DeliveryDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(today) <= 0 && amm.AuthorizedCustomers.Any(ac => ac.CustomerId.Equals(CustomerId) && ac.DeliveryDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(today)<=0)))
                  .Select(g => new ActionMenuGroup()
                  {
                      Id = g.Id,
                      Name = g.Name,
                      SortOrder = g.SortOrder,
                      ActionMenus = g.ActionMenus.Where(amm => amm.DeliveryDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(today) <= 0 && amm.AuthorizedCustomers.Any(ac => ac.CustomerId.Equals(CustomerId) && ac.DeliveryDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(today) <= 0)).ToList()
                  });
```

and all works fine!
however, after inserting a lambda filter expression the select goes wrong; here is new version with lambda:

```
public Func<Model.ActionMenu, DateTime, int?, bool> filterActionMenu = (amm, oggi, CustomerId) => amm.DeliveryDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(oggi) <= 0 && amm.AuthorizedCustomers.Any(ac => ac.CustomerId.Equals(CustomerId) && ac.DeliveryDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.MinValue).CompareTo(oggi) <= 0);

    public IQueryable<ActionMenuGroup> GetActionMenuAndMenuGroupByCustomer(int? CustomerId)
    {
        DateTime today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day);
        var actionMenuGroup = Context.ActionMenuGroups
                  .Include(am => am.ActionMenus)
                  .Where(am => am.ActionMenus.Any(amm => filterActionMenu(amm,today, CustomerId)))
                  .Select(g => new ActionMenuGroup()
                  {
                      Id = g.Id,
                      Name = g.Name,
                      SortOrder = g.SortOrder,
                      ActionMenus = g.ActionMenus.Where(amm => filterActionMenu(amm, today, CustomerId)).ToList()
                  });
        return actionMenuGroup;
    }
```

Has enyone exprerience on using lambda into linq syntax?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
public Expression<Func<Model.ActionMenu, DateTime, int?, bool>>  filterActionMenu = (amm, oggi, CustomerId) => ....
```

Comment: James, and how syntactically it can be used inside expression tree on navigation property of type `ICollection<T>`?