# E.F Core does not return all values When Include another table

Tags: c#, asp.net, frameworks, entity

```
   public IEnumerable<Parties> GetAll()
    {
        return database.Parties;
    }
```

Works very well and the output is:
[image]

But when I Include another table by foreignkey like this:

```
  public IEnumerable<Parties> GetAll()
    {
        return database.Parties.Include(i=>i.User);
    }
```

It does not work, it returns first value of the table and nothing else,the output is : [image]

Users.cs :

```
  public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        Parties = new HashSet<Parties>();
        PartyParticipants = new HashSet<PartyParticipants>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Parties> Parties { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartyParticipants> PartyParticipants { get; set; }
}
```

Parties.cs :

```
  public partial class Parties
{
    public Parties()
    {
        Image = new HashSet<Image>();
        PartyParticipants = new HashSet<PartyParticipants>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PartyDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int ParticipantCount { get; set; }
    public int MaxParticipant { get; set; }
    public string PartySplash { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public bool EntranceFree { get; set; }
    public int? FreeParticipant { get; set; }
    public int? FreeParticipantMax { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Users User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> Image { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PartyParticipants> PartyParticipants { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see on the 2nd picture it interrupts at first row of the table.
[image]

Comment: It returned the user, what did you expected to return? Did you expect parties to be populated with all parties that the user is in? If that so, You have to inclued that also,  [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties) . Also, post your classes declaration, We don't know the properties and types.

Comment: It's not returns all, as in the second picture it interrupted at parties.

Comment: We can't tell anything from the picture because you cropped it at parties. the next lines should be the parties objects that the user is in

Comment: The problem is this , I did not cropped it :D It's already as it seems. I updated the second picture.

Comment: Then you have something wrong with your json writer, because it is incomplete, as not all braces and brackets are closed. So probably the problem isn't in EF, but in the way you're displaying the results.

Comment: This will likely be because of `ReferenceLoopHandling`... Make sure it is configured to ignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added this answer based on Vidmantas's comment. `ReferenceLoopHandling` should be ignored like this in `startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```