# Why I get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two models: Order and OrderDetails. Their models:

```
public class Order
    {   
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderDetailsId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

and:

```
public class OrderDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int OrderId { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public int MenuId { get; set; }
        public Menu Menu { get; set; }
    }
```

And in the Details View of Order I wanted to show related OrderDetails. Details ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == id).Include(o => o.OrderDetails).SingleOrDefault();
            //Order order = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Id == id).Include(o => o.OrderDetails).G;
            if (order == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(order);
        }
```

And its view:

```
@model RestaurantApp.Models.Order

<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.User.Email)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.User.Email)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>


<table class="table">
    @if (Model.OrderDetails == null)
    {
        <tr>no items found</tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in Model.OrderDetails)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.MenuId</td>
                <td>@item.Quantity</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

And the problem is that I wanted to display Menu.Name instead of MenuId. But when I use Menu.Name it shows System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What EntityFramework version are you using? EF core has ThenInclude extension method for this

Comment: The real question is also a (solved) duplicate => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Manu` property is not being populated on your `OrderDetail` type. Looking at the `Details` action, it looks like you're missing to load the referenced data, similar to how you do that for the `OrderDetails` related entity.
Consider updating your query to also populate the `Menu` entity.

I assume that will be something similar to the below line (not certain about the exact syntax though):

```
.Include(o => o.OrderDetails).Include(o=>o.OrderDetails.Menu)
```

Comment: I have tried many ways of using Menu in Details method but couldn't find that right way. I tried this one too

Comment: @GulzhanatZhumazhanova Why do you not ask how to include that nested property? Just asking for "Why is it null?" is a duplicate and gets closed

Comment: Thanks for the info. This sparked my curiosity and I think this thread has the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822656/entity-framework-include-multiple-levels-of-properties