# Recursive call to navigation properties of an entity in dotnet

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am using DbContext & have a model in my web api that looks like this:
Basically each unit can have many children units, but a unit may have a single parent only.

```
public class Unit
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int ParentId {get; set;} //this aims at another Unit Id, check example for clarification.
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public List<Unit> Children {get; set;}
}
```

Now in my client side, I am trying to assign a parent to a unit, the problem is I want to only retrieve units that aren't related to my unit (Not one of its descendants).
Example: I have **X, Y, Z, M, N, O** Units.
**Y & Z** are children of **X**.
**M** is a child of **Y**.
**N** is a child of **Z**.
Now when I want to assign a parent to my **X** unit, I should only be allowed to see **O** as a viable option, since **Y** & **Z** are related to **X** (children).
And **M** & **N** are related to **X** also (grand children).
So basically my question is, how can I query a database recursively, so I keep getting children as long as they're not null & then remove them from all the Units available?
**P.S I know I can retrieve stuff in memory & then filter, but I'd rather do all that in a single query because I could have a lot of units**
Thanks!

What I tried:

1. ChatGPT suggested a solution where you use a recursive function inside the linq query itself, however that didn't work because of "Client side validation by dotnet".

Comment: You can execute a raw query that contains a recursive CTE that returns the entity set as result.

Comment: @Eldar do you mean sql? if so, can u please provide me with a snippet if u can.

Comment: It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries)

Comment: Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75507341/10646316)